# Store SQL Server sa password in secret manager

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

Is there a way to store and setup rotation of `sa` account password in AWS Secrets Manager when installing SQL Server on EC2?

All I see in Secrets Manager is options to setup database users but not the instance level users unless I create a generic `SecureString`. I would like to use `Password Rotation` functionality for `sa` user's password.

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with AWS, but is there any justifiable reason at all for using `sa` to begin with? On a regular setup (non-AWS) specific user accounts or groups should be designated as DBAs, while `sa` should either be disabled, or given a random password that is thrown away. `sa` has the drawback of being a well-known account (so an attractive target to hackers) and being impossible to audit (anyone could be logging in as `sa`).

Comment: Valid point but when you are dealing with armchair DBAs in their 50s and 60s and they say they want `sa` or you don't get paid, ,they get `sa`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special with a `Password Rotation` functionality that wouldn't work with any kind of secret.

When you're enabling the password rotation, what you do is set up a Lambda function that will do the rotation. In AWS documentation you can find a template for a function that is doing the rotation on the RDS database and you can modify the code for that function to make the update you need. As long as you can make the change for `sa` programmatically from a Lambda function, you can use the `Rotation` functionality of a Secrets manager

Comment: I understand that and I am trying to avoid writing a lambda function that will change `sa` password on the instance.

Comment: @Asdfg unfortunately, secret rotation in AWS works by using the Lambda function, so there's not much you can do if you don't want to write a Lambda function

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out alternative solution that does not use lambda.

Comment: @Asdfg it would be nice if you can share how you did it in the end :)